# Explode Hive Map data object into long format

Tags: hadoop, hive, keyvaluepair

I have a map data type in a table with fairly large number of key, values (10-30). When I explode the key, values, I get below:

```
SELECT id, key,value
FROM tbl1
lateral view explode(map_field) feature_cols
```

Results:

```
id, key1, value1
id, key2, value2
id, key3, value3
```

However, I would like to see:

```
id, key1, key2, key3
1, value1, valu2, value3
```

Is there any command that either produces my desired format, or is there any command to convert exploded output to the long format I desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to transpose Columns into Rows after lateral view explode. You can write query like as stated below.

```
Select 
id, 
 Case when key=key1 then value1 as      key1,
Case when key=key2 then value2 as key2,
Case when key=key3 then value3 as key3
From
```

(SELECT id, key,value FROM tbl1 lateral    view explode(map_field) feature_cols) temp

Comment: Thanks. But considering long number of pairs, it will be very long process to type the code manually. Is there any function we can use to transpose like the way we transpose matrix?

Comment: @Espanta No, in Hive there is no alternative implementation approach.
You can achieve this task in Spark.

Comment: I am accepting your answer hoping it can help those in need with smaller number of features